# Compare two time in MM:SS format

Tags: java, time

I am looking to compare two times in MM:SS format and get the difference between these two in seconds

For eg 
time 1 = 20:28
, time 2 = 20:18

The difference is -10 seconds

I have tried to use following approach to compare the time

```
        LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "20:28" );
        LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse( "20:18" );
        Duration duration = Duration.between( start, stop );
        System.out.println(duration.getSeconds());
```

**Actual** : This prints `-600` seconds as output, because time is parsed in HH: MM format.

**Expected** `-10`

Is there any other approach using which I can get the expected output considering MM:SS format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `LocalTime` seems to be unable to use a `DateTimeFormatter` pattern of `mm:ss`, you can also make a short `static` helper method that is called instead.

This method sets a default hour for all parses to the same value, which does not expose the `"00:"` anywhere else which could be bug prone if a different hour is accidentally entered.

This will ensure any `Duration.between()` for minutes and seconds will be accurate:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    LocalTime start = parseHelper("20:28");
    LocalTime stop = parseHelper("20:18");
    Duration duration = Duration.between(start, stop);
    System.out.println(duration.getSeconds());
}

private static LocalTime parseHelper(String str) {
    return LocalTime.parse("00:" + str);
}
```

**Output:**

> -10

**EDIT:**

[Here are some docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#toString--) that reinforce that `hours` are not optional in `LocalTime`, and apparently neither are `minutes`.

Here you can see they list the possible values in the `toString()` method.

> The output will be one of the following ISO-8601 formats:

```
HH:mm
HH:mm:ss
HH:mm:ss.SSS
HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS
HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSS
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "00:20:28" );
    LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse( "00:20:18" );
    Duration duration = Duration.between( start, stop );
    System.out.println(duration.getSeconds());
```

You are saving date in wrong manner. you also have to provide hour. when you pass 2 parameter(20:18), Its consider first as hour second as minute. thats why its returning 600 second. 600 sec is equal to 10 minute. which is time difference between your both parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You may be using `LocalTime` incorrectly.

Assuming that you want what you say you want, the trick is to define a formatter that assumes that hour of day is 0. The `parseDefaulting` method of `DateTImeFormatterBuilder` is what we need for this:

```
    DateTimeFormatter mmssFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("mm:ss")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .toFormatter();

    LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "20:28", mmssFormatter );
    LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse( "20:18", mmssFormatter );
    Duration duration = Duration.between( start, stop );
    System.out.println(duration.getSeconds());
```

Output is:

> -10

The time strings are parsed into times of 00:20:28 and 00:20:18. What I don’t understand is what sense it makes to restrict yourself to times between 00:00:00 and 01:00:00 in the night. If instead your times are relative to some point that is not necessarily 00:00, it may be more correct to use `Duration` for them too. The idea being that 20:28 is not a time of day, but can be seen as the duration between the base of your measurement and the start time. You can then subtract the durations:

```
    Duration relativeStart = parseDuration("20:28");
    Duration relativeStop = parseDuration("20:18");
    Duration duration = relativeStop.minus(relativeStart);
    System.out.println(duration.getSeconds());
```

I am using this auxiliary method:

```
private static Duration parseDuration(String timeString) {
    String isoTimeString = timeString.replaceFirst("(\\d{2}):(\\d{2})", "PT$1M$2S");
    return Duration.parse(isoTimeString);
}
```

Since `Duration.parse` can only parse a string in ISO 8601 format, like `PT20M28S`, I use a regular expression for converting your string to this format.

Output is the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you cannot have a formatter with just minutes and seconds, hour is mandatory. A possible approach is to prepend a default hour to your string:

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("00:20:28");
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse("00:20:18");
Duration duration = Duration.between( start, stop );
System.out.println(duration.getSeconds());
```

Output: `-10`

Another possible approach is to use the `of` method with a default hour:

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of(0, 20, 28);
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of(0, 20, 18);
Duration duration = Duration.between( start, stop );
System.out.println(duration.getSeconds());
```

Output: `-10`

Comment: "you cannot have a formatter with just minutes and seconds" - This isn't true. The reason why OP's code doesn't work is because no `DateTimeFormatter` can parse `mm:ss` as a `LocalTime` object.

Comment: @JacobG. Even if you create a `DateTimeFormatter` with `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("mm:ss")` you'll get an exception that disappears once you add hours. So maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me that `DateTimeFormatter` expects given format to contain hours when dealing with time.

Comment: yes , when tried with `DateTimeFormatter dt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM:SS");` , throws `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException` .

Comment: I knew I can append 00 as a prefix to the time and continue, but I wasn't sure if this is the only way .

Comment: @Maverick In your specific case the issue is that capital M stands for month and capital S stands for milliseconds, you have to use `mm:ss` instead. But it won't work either

Comment: yeah, I will prepend hour. Thanks, guys

Comment: @Maverick You're welcome! Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it resolved your issue.